# Is it possible to use battery for the wired keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

The wire of my keyboard is destroyed. But  Inside the keyboard I saw there is a place to insert battery. Is it possible to use battery and use the keyboard without wire and usb port? I don't know why there is a place for battery because I doubt the that thia is a bluetooth keybaord.
For more information it is "UC tech KB4600"
Here is picture of that:[image]

Comment: The batter compartment isn't hook into anything, there are not even contacts, putting a battery in would do nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use battery and use the keyboard without wire and usb port?

The battery compartment isn't connected to anything.  There are not even contacts, so installing a battery in that particular keyboard, wouldn't do anything.  **The circuit on the PCB is not even connected.** The manufacture would have designed a second version of the circuit, and simply used the same blank board, when they manufactured the board itself.

> I don't know why there is a place for battery because I doubt the that this is a Bluetooth keyboard.

The manufacture designed a single PCB in order to save money.  A small amount of work at the factory would need to be done to make that a wireless keyboard.  The keyboard shown in the screenshot is not wireless and does not have the electronics to be turned into a wireless keyboard.  **Your keyboard absolutely is not a Bluetooth keyboard.**

Comment: I have personal experience designing a PCB, an engineer would layout the common elements, then have several versions of the same board layout more than likely.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not possible. The same plastic case can just be used on many keyboard models, some with electronics for wired connectivity and some with electronics for wireless connectivity.